# Set of equivalence classes of a Lie algebra under the action of the automorphism group

Tags: lie-algebras, automorphisms

I recently became interested in the following question: Given a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$, define two elements $x,y\in\mathfrak{g}$ to be equivalent if there exists an automorphism $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ such that $\phi(x)=y$. Are there particular cases where one can understand this set? Any reference to results in this direction is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So you are interested in the orbits of the action of $\mathrm{Aut}({\mathfrak g)}$ on $L$. When ${\mathfrak g}$ is abelian you just have 2 orbits but, of course, this is only a trivial case.

Comment: For gl(n) there is the Noether-Skolem theorem, so then you are thrown back to classifying conjugy classes. This is linear algebra then.

Comment: For semisimple Lie algebras you can link orbits of nilpotent elements to orbits of parabolic subalgebras (I think this may be orbits of $\mathrm{Inn}(\mathfrak{g})$ which in this case is the connected component of the identity of $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$). Key words are Bala-Carter theory, Jacobson-Morozov parabolics and Richardson orbits.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments and references!